# No such module 'AWS...' with Xcode 9.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

I recently updated Xcode to Version 9.3.1 and I started to get errors of this type in one of my project:

```
No such module 'AWSCore'
No such module 'AWSS3'
No such module 'AWSDynamoDB'
No such module 'AWSDynamoDB'
No such module 'AWSMobileClient'
```

for these lines of code:

```
import AWSCore
import AWSS3
import AWSDynamoDB
import AWSDynamoDB
import AWSMobileClient
```

The errors were not showing up before.

I did the classical Build Cleaning and rebuilding several times.
I went to remove the DerivedData from the command line.
I also made a "pod update" and got newer AWSxxx pods.

But I still keep getting the same errors.

Anyone experienced the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Open .xcworkspace from project file and build and run.

Comment: "Opening .xcworkspace then build and run" is what I have always been doing. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Pod installation creates new workspace with projectName.xcworkspace. Default project opens from .xcodeproj. If you open project from projectName.xcodeproj then it will not detect pod files.

Comment: I open the only workspace I have (it may be new, after an update, as you mention), after running pod, as I have always been doing and I get the problem I explain in my post.

Comment: Close Xcode, go to terminal and cd to the project folder. `pod deintegrate` then `pod install`. If that doesn't fix the issue then you might have to link the framework back to your project manually.

Comment: I did it, it did not work first. Then I went to Build Phases, to remove everything I had put in between(that is the AWSxxx frameworks). Now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I need to add that the error seems to reappear at random once in a while.